# How to pattern match the runtimeType of a freezed class?

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-freezed

I am implementing an infinite scroll list for a home feed in a Flutter app. The list contains different items that are rendered with different widgets. I use the freezed package to create domain models that I initialize with the response from an API. Now I need some way to differentiate the models to render the correct widget. I decided to create a general HomeFeedItem widget, that does the rendering.

```dart
class HomeFeedItem extends StatelessWidget {
  final dynamic item;

  const HomeFeedItem({Key? key, required this.item}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    final Widget widget;

    switch (item.runtimeType) {
      case TodayDivider:
        widget = const TodayDivider();
      case DateDivider:
        widget = DateDivider(date: item.date);
      case CheckinCTA:
        widget = const CheckinCTA();
      case EntryPreview:
        widget = EntryPreview(
          id: item.id,
          title: item.title,
          summary: item.summary,
        );
      default:
        widget = const Text('Unknown item type');
    }

    return Column(
      children: [
        widget,
        const SizedBox(height: 24),
      ],
    );
  }
}
```

The issue is that for example of `EntryPreview` the `runtimeType` is `_$EntryPreviewImpl`, which is private. So this approach fails and every item is `Text("Unknown item type")`

I could add a getter to each model that returns a type. But I was wondering if there isn't a better way to pattern match the type of a freezed class.

Comment: You shouldn't be relying on runtimeType in your case (Freezed) then

Comment: what abt `item is TodayDivider` with `if` and `else` ?

Comment: seems like https://dart.dev/language/pattern-types#object would help

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Doing:

```dart
switch (item.runtimeType) {
  case TodayDivider:
    ...
```

uses a [constant pattern](https://dart.dev/language/pattern-types#constant) that compares the `Type` object returned by `item.runtimeType` for equality.  Equality for `Type` objects is object identity; they compare equal only to themselves regardless of relationships between types.

You instead should use a [variable pattern](https://dart.dev/language/pattern-types#variable) that matches `item` and not `item.runtimeType`:

```dart
    switch (item) {
      case TodayDivider _:
        widget = const TodayDivider();
      case DateDivider item:
        widget = DateDivider(date: item.date);
      case CheckinCTA _:
        widget = const CheckinCTA();
      case EntryPreview item:
        widget = EntryPreview(
          id: item.id,
          title: item.title,
          summary: item.summary,
        );
      default:
        widget = const Text('Unknown item type');
    }
```

Comment: btw is there any difference in variable vs object pattern matching? I mean `case TodayDivider _:` vs `case TodayDivider():` and the same for  other cases?

Comment: @pskink You'd want to use the variable pattern if you want a variable with that static type, but for the `_` cases where the variable isn't used, using an object pattern would work too.

Comment: ah I see, and speaking about object pattern, do you by any chance know what `'Function'` literal mean in object pattern syntax: https://github.com/dart-lang/language/blob/main/accepted/3.0/patterns/feature-specification.md#object-pattern, I tried to find anything but failed...  the full syntax: `(typeName typeArguments? | (typeIdentifier '.')? 'Function')
    '(' patternFields? ')'`

Comment: @pskink Digging through the commit history for that spec file led me to https://github.com/dart-lang/sdk/issues/54246

Comment: James, thanks for the explanation, it's more clear now